# Content in Hyperlink Button doesnt show

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

Im currently trying to add some Style to my Hyperlinkbutton, but cannot get it to work.

After some searching, I  found this Tutorial, but even after copying the whole code (and only changing the picture) it doesnt work for me. My SDK-Target is 7.5.

Here my Code:

```
   <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="/Views/PanoramaPage.xaml" Content="Panorama" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>
            <HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="/Views/PanoramaPage.xaml" Content="Pivot" Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"/>

            <HyperlinkButton Name="hyperlinkButton1" NavigateUri="/Views/PanoramaPage.xaml" >
                <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="5" Padding="10">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Width="60" Source="/Presentation;component/Images/refresh.png" />
                        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Go to View.xaml"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </HyperlinkButton>

        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Tutorial-Url:
http://www.imaginativeuniversal.com/blog/post/2010/07/05/Navigating-around-windows-phone-7.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default control template for the HyperlinkButton is a TextBlock, so all it can handle is text!

One way to go around this is to change the control template, like this:

```
<HyperlinkButton Name="hyperlinkButton1" NavigateUri="/Views/PanoramaPage.xaml">
    <HyperlinkButton.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
            <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="5" Padding="10">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Width="60" Source="/Presentation;component/Images/refresh.png" />
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Go to View.xaml"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </HyperlinkButton.Template>
</HyperlinkButton>
```

Comment: The content dependency property of a hyperlinkbutton can be anything not just text.

Comment: You're right @DaveS, but it just wont show up: the default HyperlinkButton template only shows text!!!

Comment: How does the Tutorial then work (with the Border)? I just think that the HyperlinkButton himself is pretty ugly and wanted it to look like a Button.

Comment: What Tutorial? Can you post the link?

Comment: Damn, did I forgot it to post? I add it to the Question

Comment: That doesn't work, can't remember if it did with the Windows Phone 7.0 SDK, but it doesn't currently work! Just tryed it with Blend and confirmed what I just told you: use a template to change HyperlinkButton look!

Comment: Sad that it doesnt work like in the post, smaller and prettier. Anyways, your solution works :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10331/discussion-between-pedro-lamas-and-gnrlknowledge)