# Hyperlink button content not showing

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I am creating a hyperlink button like this :

```
<HyperlinkButton Name="Button"  Background="#11A3EB"  Height="29" Width="128" >
                <HyperlinkButton.Content>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="../../Assets/Images/Image.png" Width="20" Height="20"/>
                        <sdk:Label Content="Some Text" Padding="5,0,0,0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </HyperlinkButton.Content>
            </HyperlinkButton>
```

The result is fine in the design preview of visual studio.

However, when i compile my application, the button shows a rectangle with nothing inside it.

Why is not showing correctly and how should i solve this problem ?

Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246697/content-in-hyperlink-button-doesnt-show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set Foreground property value some other color than #11A3EB. Maybe your button text color is the same as you link background.

Comment: No, that's not it. the background color is blue and the foreground color is white and nothing shows.

Comment: I created such control on local environment without sdk:Label control using simple TextBlock everything displays as normal. Try to replace your sdk:Label.

Comment: hmm, it doesn't work with a TextBlock on my side. It only works if I write <HyperLinkButton content="some text" />.

Comment: Maybe HyperLinkButton have some overridden functionality and can't accept anything beside strings. Also try to use another wrapping container and also try to use only textblock as content without StackPanel and Image

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that the paths to the image will be different between the development environment and the deployed version will have a different path.

Also check to make sure that the image is set to be included in the compiled solution.

I think the best thing to do is to include the image as a resource and then use a resource link, this is a good article that covers the various pros & cons - http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/wp7-working-with-images-content-vs-resource-build-action

HTH,
Rupert.

Comment: Hello, I don't think it has to do with the image in my case. When I comment the <image> , the button is still empty. I guess it has to do with the <HyperlinkButton.Content> but i don't know why.